# How can I fix this background colour issue?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I want this dark mode tkinter page but it automatically puts a patch of white around every widget because the default widget colour is black and it wouldn't show. To eliminate this I put the background as black and the foreground as white but now there are random white patches so can it be fixed? Here's my code:

import tkinter as tk

```
root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root["bg"] = "#000000"
root.title("R-Net")

welcome_label = tk.Label(text = "Welcome!\nLog in:", font=(60), bg = "black",fg = "white")
welcome_label.place(relx=.5, rely=0, anchor = "n")

main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_label = tk.Label(main_frame, text = "Enter username and password:", bg = "black",fg = "white", font=(30))
main_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
username_entry = tk.Entry(main_frame, width = 100, fg = "white", bg = "black")
username_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
main_frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor = "center")

root.mainloop()
```

As you can see if you run the code, there are white patches near `main_label` but I don't know why.

Comment: Btw you are missing `root` from your `welcome_label = tk.Label(...)` line. Change it to `welcome_label = tk.Label(root, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you define a label that takes up a lot of place you need to give it the 'sticky' or 'fill' kwargs depending on which geometry manager you use to say that this is part of the label. Basically what sticky does is that it tells grid that this label is spanning these directions and has stretched out more than it should so consider these parts as the label. Your code fixed by just adding 'sticky=tk.EW' like below (if you need more explanation, feel free to leave it at the comments):

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
root.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
root["bg"] = "#000000"
root.title("R-Net")

welcome_label = tk.Label(root, text = "Welcome!\nLog in:", font=(60), bg = "black",fg = "white")
welcome_label.place(relx=.5, rely=0, anchor = "n")

main_frame = tk.Frame(root)
main_label = tk.Label(main_frame, text = "Enter username and password:", bg = "black", fg = "white", font=(30))
# Just added 'sticky=tk.EW' to your code and it fixed the problem
main_label.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.EW)
username_entry = tk.Entry(main_frame, width = 100, fg = "white", bg = "black")
username_entry.grid(row=1, column=0)
main_frame.place(relx=.5, rely=.5, anchor = "center")

root.mainloop()
```